# How to write UTF-8 or Base64 data into a file (jpg/doc/pdf) on local storage(sdcard) in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, fileapi

I am getting byte array like var byteArr=[12,-123,43,99, ...] from API,
Then I am converting it into UTF-8 String by

```
     var utf8_str = String.fromCharCode.apply([], new Uint8Array(byteArr));
```

Then converting UTF-8 string to Base64 string by

```
      var base64_str= window.btoa(utf8_str);
```

Now I am writing UTF-8 or Base64 string to file (xyz.pdf/xyz.jpg) by FileWriter in Phonegap, but it show me blank file when open it.

```
function gotWriteFile(dirEntry) {

   dirEntry.getFile(FILE_NAME, {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileWriteEntry,  failWrite);
}

function gotFileWriteEntry(fileEntry) {

fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, failWrite);
}

function gotFileWriter(writer) {

 writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
        console.log("File write successfully....");
        hideModal();
    };
    writer.write(utf8_str);
    //writer.write(base64_str);
 }
```

What is solution guys.... ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found solution to create file by byte array in Phonegap.

In phonegap, Text and Binary data are supported for Android and iOS to write into file. So I have convert BYTE array to BINARY array, then write by FileWriter.

```
 var byteArr=[12,-123,43,99, ...] ;
 var UTF8_STR = new Uint8Array(byteArr);  // Convert to UTF-8...                
 var BINARY_ARR=UTF8_STR.buffer;         // Convert to buffer...
```

Then pass 'BINARY_ARR' to FileWriter to write in file.

```
 function gotFileWriter(writer) {
     writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
     console.log("File write successfully....");        
   };
   writer.write(BINARY_ARR);   
 }
```

Have a nice day.. :)

Comment: I am trying to save a png file to the filesystem  that i have in a  base64 string . Can you pls help me out

Comment: have you solved problem or still facing problem? @Vijar

Comment: i am still facing a problem, i am new to javascript so can you please tell me how i can apply your soln with a base64 string instead of a byte array like you have used @Saurabh

Comment: would i have to use atob?

Comment: Try this code..   /*
 * Convert Base64 -> Binary -> Blob  -> write to file
 */
function dataFile(bs64data)
{
    var binary = atob(bs64data.split(',')[1]); // atob() decode base64 data..
    var array = [];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) 
    {
      array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i)); // convert to binary..
    }
    var file = new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {type: 'image/jpeg'});  // create blob file..
}

Comment: Then return file variable to filewriter to write file. @vijar

Comment: I believe blob is only partially supported on android and is deprecated. Can you edit for array buffer. Thanks i appreciate the help

Comment: Thanks for all the help i got it to work . Now i was wondering if you know how to view the saved image in the gallery in IOS ?

Answer (score 1):

try this (make sure u are getting utf8_str properly):

```
var utf8_str = String.fromCharCode.apply([], new Uint8Array(byteArr));
var base64_str= window.btoa(utf8_str);
function writeFile() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}
function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile(FILE_NAME, {create: true}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}
function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
}
function gotFileWriter(writer) {
    writer.onwrite = function (evt) {
        alert('done');
    }
    writer.write(utf8_str);
}
function fail(error) {
    console.log(error.code);
}
```

Comment: I tried this example from phonegap DOCS, but not usefull. @Vicky

Comment: are u are getting utf8_str properly?

Answer (score 0):

I had issues on another project with `btoa` not doing a proper conversion, so I ended up using [Base64 binary](https://github.com/danguer/blog-examples/blob/master/js/base64-binary.js) in my project to decode the Base64 response.

What I noticed was that the file I transferred was bigger when saved on the phone compared to the file residing on the server.

Maybe that is the case for you as well?

Comment: when I am getting data by 'btoa', images/pdf are showing in browser but when saving in mobile by File writer, its show blank file..

Comment: When you say blank file, do you mean file size 0 or something else?